# Django add new Model and Form in a new app

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

i am using Django and trying to add a new model which can only be accessed after user login. Firstly, i built a model class of UserProfile in an app, using

```
def create_user_profile(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        UserProfile.objects.create(user=instance) 
post_save.connect(create_user_profile, sender=User)
```

to sync the model into database, it works well by calling `UserProfile = request.user.get_profile()`, then i built Anther model class called "ControlInformation" in ANOTHER app (called "control"), using

```
def create_control_information(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        ControlInformation.objects.create(user=instance)
post_save.connect(create_control_information, sender=User)
```

to sync this model, but there are some problems to use information in this model by calling `Current_Status = request.user.get_profile()` , which is "'UserProfile' object has no attribute 'turn_on_off'" when calling `on_off = Current_Status.turn_on_off` in views.py.

Am i right when building this one on one model in another app? Or is there any other problem?

Edit:
my ControlInformation model is like this:

```
class ControlInformation(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

    TURN_ON_OFF = (
        ('ON', 'On'),
        ('OFF', 'Off'),
    )

    AUTO_MANU = (
        ('ON', 'On'),
        ('OFF', 'Off'),
    )

    TEMP_DINNINGROOM = (
        ('HIGH', 'High'),
        ('MEDIUM', 'Medium'),
        ('LOW', 'Low'),
    )

    TEMP_LIVINGROOM = (
        ('HIGH', 'High'),
        ('MEDIUM', 'Medium'),
        ('LOW', 'Low'),
    )

    turn_on_off = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TURN_ON_OFF)
    auto_manu = models.CharField(max_length = 1, choices=AUTO_MANU)
    temp_dinningroom = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TEMP_DINNINGROOM)
    temp_livingroom = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=TEMP_LIVINGROOM)

#signal function: if a user is created, add control information to the user    
def create_control_information(sender, instance, created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        ControlInformation.objects.create(user=instance)

post_save.connect(create_control_information, sender=User)
```

Then i use this model in views.py like this:

```
def current_status(request):
    if not request.user.is_authenticated():
        return HttpResponseRedirect('/keenhome/accounts/login/')
    Current_Status = request.user.get_profile()  

    on_off = Current_Status.turn_on_off
    auto_manu = Current_Status.auto_manu
    temp_dinningroom = Current_Status.temp_dinningroom
    temp_livingroom = Current_Status.temp_livingroom

    context = {'on_off': on_off,
               'auto_manu': auto_manu,
               'temp_dinningroom': temp_dinningroom, 
               'temp_livingroom': temp_livingroom,
               }
    return render(request, 'control/current_control_status.html', context)
```

The `on_off = Current_Status.turn_on_off` is where problem happens. ('UserProfile' object has no attribute 'auto_manu')

Comment: What you are trying to do is acceptable. Can you show the `UserProfile` model ? Or just veify if the `UserProfile` has a `turn_on_off` attribute

Comment: Hi Karthikr, i updated it. Could you help me about it?

Comment: One more question. WHat is the type of model `request.user.get_profile()` returns. I am assuming, it returns `UserProfile` rather than `ControlInformation` you are expecting

Comment: Oh, i think so. I use `request.user.get_profile()` because i thought my `ControlInformation` model is attached to UserProfile and `request.user.get_profile()` returns all the user profile so i can call attributes in it. If this is wrong, how can i call the `ControlInformation` rather than `UserProfile`?

Comment: You mean you want to change `request.user.get_profile` to return `ControlInformation` instance instead, I would just recommend keep things the way they are, and query in the view wherever you are looking for `ControlInformation` object ?

Comment: No, i have another view function in anther app using `request.user.get_profile` to return the user profile. Here in this app's view, i hope to return the informations in ControlInformation model. ControlInformation model is created as `OneToOneField`.

Comment: ok. i shall post this as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you already have `request.user.get_profile()` to return `UserProfile` model, You are looking for `ControlInformation` object in this case. So, just change

```
Current_Status = request.user.get_profile()
```

to

```
Current_Status = ControlInformation.objects.get(user=request.user)
```

Or,

```
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
Current_Status = get_object_or_404(ControlInformation, user=request.user)
```

Comment: Hi Karthikr, thanks for your help, this works for getting the `ControlInformation` and present it on the web, but after i tried to modify and save the values in this model, there is not any change. I used `form.save()` methods to save the information. How can i modify this?